# Children die of Poverty, Yet ALLAH tells us that ALLAH will provide for them. I am confused?

Tags: quran, tafseer

[b/Israel 17:31] And do not kill your children, fearing poverty; We shall provide sustenance to them as well as to you; indeed killing them is a great mistake.

ALLAH says that ALLAH will provide sustenance for them, so why do children die out of poverty in the world? I am confused. Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: I saw a similar question on the site a few weeks ago I'm pretty sure it was answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ayah is not a promise that Allah will provide for people, but rather it is a factual statement that Allah is the one responsible for giving sustenance:

> And do not kill your children, fearing poverty; **We provide sustenance to them and to you**; indeed killing them is a great mistake.

Basically, the purpose of the phrase "we provide sustenance for them and for you" is a reminder to parents contemplating killing their children for fear of starvation that Allah is responsible for apportioning sustenance. Their killing of their children will not increase the sustenance Allah has already apportioned for them, or stop them from starvation if they were destined to it.